# 'cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, parameters

Using in and out parameters, I get the error "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to object". Not sure why it's doing this or how to fix it. Does anyone know a solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParameterPassing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b, c;
            int[] list = new int[5];
            ParameterTest p = new ParameterTest(3);

            Console.WriteLine("Without method: {0}", a);

            Console.WriteLine("After the method: {0}", p.Value(a));

            Console.WriteLine("Using the Swap method: {0}", p.Swap(ref a));

            Console.WriteLine("Here is an array: {0}", p.OddEven(out b, out c));

        }
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
namespace ParameterPassing
{
    class ParameterTest
    {
        private int integer = 3;


        public ParameterTest(int myInt)
        {
            integer = myInt;
        }

        public int Value(int a)
        {
            a = 0;
            return a;
        }

        public int Swap(ref int b)
        {
            b = b * 4;
            return b;
        }

        public void OddEven(out int odd, out int even)
        {
            even = 0;
            odd = 0;
            int[] array = new int[5];
            Random generator = new Random(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = generator.Next(100);
            }

            foreach (int item in array)
            {
                if (item % 2 == 0)
                {
                    even = even++;
                }
                else
                {
                    odd = odd++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The number of odd numbers in the array is: {0}", odd);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of even numbers in the array is: {1}", even);
        }
    }
}
```

The error comes from the line the fourth `Console.WriteLine` at the top of the program, specifically in the part that is intended to output `p.OddEven`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `OddEven` is `void` so it returned nothing.

`WriteLine` is expecting something returned as the second parameter just like in your other methods.
You would need to call the method outside of the `WriteLine`.

If you want to print the value of `a` and `b` then you can pass `a` and `b` into your `Console.WriteLine` after calling the `OddEven` method.

Answer (score 0):

`OddEven` type is `void` therefore you can't use it in the 4th `Console.WriteLine`. Either change the type and make `OddEven` return something or dont try to print its result.